# Bluemix Push Notification with userID

Tags: push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I am using the latest Bluemix Push Notification service. I'm using the MFPPush API to register the device (Android).

Here is my code snippet:

```
var success = function(message) 
{ 
    console.log("Success: " + message);
    alert("Reg Device: " + message);
};
var failure = function(message) 
{ 
    console.log("Error: " + message); 
    alert("Error: " + message);
};
MFPPush.registerDevice({}, success, failure);
var notification = function(notification)
{
    // notification is a JSON object.
    alert(notification.message);
};
MFPPush.registerNotificationsCallback(notification);
```

The success message contains the following information:

```
Token:APA91bFtkSr59Zxlr52HU****Uij
UserId: ""
DeviceId: g5c6d98f-0867-3fd1-a353-15bcdef675a2
```

When I send the notification, my device receives the message.

The Swagger REST API shows that I can arbitrarily give some token, `userId` and `deviceId`:

```
{
  "deviceId": "TestDeviceId",
  "platform": "G",
  "token": "************",
  "userId": "Joe"
}
```

How do I get the `"TestDeviceId"`, and how do I get the `"token"`?  I don't see any API to get that information.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: You should probably just use the Client SDK to register as it handles all of this in the background--automatically assigning each device a unique ID. You shouldn't explore this unless you know what you're doing. There isn't a really a reason for trying to manually set the deviceID.**

When you register a device for the Push Notifications service, you set these values in the body of the POST request. On a successful call, it will return these values in the response. I'll do a demo of this later in the post.

[image: register]

You can also retrieve a list of the device registrations for the Push Notifications service.
[image: get devices]

You can use that `deviceId` to retrieved detailed information about the device, send a specific push notification to that device, subscribe it to a tag and send push notifications to those devices, etc.

[Swagger Documentation is here.](https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfpushrestapidocs/#!/devices/post_apps_applicationId_devices)

---

Regarding those values, you can put whatever you want in them when you register. Typically, these values would be set automatically by the Bluemix Mobile Android/iOS Client SDK when you do the register call. However, you could do this manually using the REST client.

**For example:**

Here, I'm registering a device:

[image: registering]

It registered successfully:
[image: successful response]

This is what I get if I ask the Push Notifications service for information about my registered devices (for the `"deviceId": "arandomdeviceid"`):

[image: querying]

The Android BMS Core Client SDK sets this `deviceId` using a unique UUID from the device and hashing it with MD5.

[You can look in here more more information about that.](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-android-core)

Comment: I want to use the MFPPush.register({}, success, false) JS function to register the device.  Can I pass my deviceId, userId information inside the {}.  If yes, I need the sample JSON.

Comment: The Client SDK is just a wrapper around the REST API. It doesn't support the ability to set these parameters from the SDK. However, you could make a REST request from your application to achieve the functionality that you want.

Comment: By the way, is there a reason you need this functionality? I think you might be causing more trouble for yourself then you need.

Comment: I thought using the Client SDK is mush more easier rather than understanding the REST API and ensuring I pass all the information like appSecret, application ID etc.  I don't see the point of having a Client SDK if I cannot pass those information.  I understand having a simple call if someone does not need to pass any information, but it should ensure that it covers everything that can be done with REST.  That is the point of a wrapper, hiding the complexity from the end user.  It looks like an half baked job.  Hope the Client SDK developers watch this post and do the necessary.  Thanks

Comment: The Client SDK includes all of the necessary code for registering, receiving push notifications, getting tags, subscribing to tags, etc. What you seem to be looking for here is extended, complex behavior that is abstracted from the developer, deep in the Core SDK. You can achieve this extended behavior by using a simple REST call, but I can't think of a use-case of why a developer would want to manually set a unique `deviceId` (which is why it isn't in the Client SDK spec).

Comment: If you let me know why you think this should be included (e.g. your use-case), we can have a discussion with the developers about adding this to the spec.

Comment: My scenario is for users who use the same Id from multiple devices and want to get notified in all the devices.  

Details:  
The registration is done using my client Cordova (right now only Android) app. The user then makes some transactions using the app.The backend process after the transaction is completed sends notification to that user.  User might have multiple devices with the app (registered with same userid) and notification has to be sent to all the devices.
I want to use the Client SDK for registration and the backend process will use the REST API for sending notification.

Comment: For me storing the userId and sending notification based on that is more important.  I don't care about the deviceId.

Comment: I will speak with the SDK developers about your feedback and use-case.

Comment: Also, I would recommend familiarizing yourself with tags and tag subscription because it seems like that could be a solution to your problem. You can create a tag and subscribe devices to that tag. When you send a push notification to that tag, it will alert all the devices subscribed to it.

Comment: Based on your suggestion if I register the device using REST API, how will I get the deviceId and token which are generated by the Android device automatially?  
Until I get an answer for the above question and an updated Client SDK which makes it easier for me here is the workaround I am using:
1.  Register the device using MFPPush.register({}, success, failure).  In the success message I get the deviceId and token.  I save it.
2.  Make a REST API call to update the registration with a unique userId.  I use the deviceId and token which I obtained in the first step.

Comment: You can make a tag for each user and subscribe each device they own to that tag. Then when you send a notification to the tag, it will alert all of the devices for that user.

Comment: You can register and subscribe to the tags with the client SDK.

Comment: Yes that could be a workaround but think adding a tag for each user and if there are million users...you might end up with that many tags.  Not sure if tag is meant for that kind of purpose

Comment: It would be great if the following enhancements are done.
(a)  Allow userId parameter to be passed along with the MFPPush registration like MFPPush.register({"userId": "AUniqueUserId"}, success, failure)
(b)  Add an additional parameter to the target "userIds" (array).  Internally this call would  look for all the deviceIds for each of the userId and send notification.

Thanks for all your help and time spent

Answer (score 0):

@anamica (a) Allow userId parameter to be passed along with the MFPPush registration like MFPPush.register({"userId": "AUniqueUserId"}, success, failure) (b) Add an additional parameter to the target "userIds" (array). 
This enhancement has been done, you can give a try by updating the latest SDK.